# How to stop an Activity from parent Activity?

Tags: android

```
_alerts = new Intent(homeActivity,Alertss.class);
homeActivity.startActivity(_alerts);
...
...
...
homeActivity.stopService(_alerts);
```

I need to stop the Activity i created from the object where i created it. I tried it in the way above but it did not work. Can any one suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: @dinesh707: "I need to stop the Activity i created from the object where i created it." -- no, you don't. Please explain what the real problem is that you are trying to solve, so we can suggest a better course of action.

Comment: `stopService` is for services started with `startService`.

Comment: just an observation. If you launch the second activity it will bring to the front of the parent, than the parent will go in the `onPause` state.So when the parent should close the second activity?

Comment: I'm opening an Alert kind of a window at the beginning of the homeActivity. So in the background homeActivity runs. There is a timer counting down and when timer reach zero it needs to open a new Activity (finalActivity). Before i start finalActivity I need to stop (or kill) the alert activity.

Comment: so you need a custom alert dialog which is not an activity

Comment: @Francesco: Background activity does not stop. I run the _alert activity on DialogTheam. There i can see the background activity works and counting down.

Comment: @dinesh707: Get rid of the alert activity and integrate its contents into the home activity or the final activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Activity.startActivityForResult() and then Activity.finishActivity() passing in the same result code you used for starting it.

However, this does sound like something that would be better done just as a Dialog.